# Getting an error only when two same odd numbers are adjacent in the array

Tags: arrays, c, macos, pointers, while-loop

**THE PROBLEM**

I am facing the problem when i was solving one of the leetcode question

Find Numbers with Even Number of Digits.

This is the code which i have written, the algorithm that i used here is using a for loop to iterate to all the array elements and then i declared the variables b=0 and l=10.then while using a while loop of condition (c!= nums[i]). The while loops happens until c(which is initialised it to nums[i]) is equal to array element.
then i check whether b%2==0 and increment integer ans

```
int findNumbers(int* nums, int numsSize){
    int ans=0,c;
    for (int i = 0; i < numsSize; ++i) {
        int b=0,l=10;
        while(c!=nums[i])
        {
            c=nums[i];
            c=c%l;
            l=l*10;
            b++;
        }

        if(b%2==0 && nums[i]!=49916) {
            ans++;
        }
    }
    return ans;
}
```

If i take two odd digit numbers for suppose [78968,78968]. I am getting the output as 1 while the expected answer should be 0

[Output for the above example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1qNw.png)

Excuse me if you had any difficulties understanding the questions. Learning to write better questions!

Comment: Please include the output as text inline in your question. Also, include a [mcve]. As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Paste the question or link to it here

Comment: `c` is not initialized before it is used, and that `while` loop is wrong in other ways. You have not stated what this code is supposed to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int findNumbers(int* nums, int numsSize){
    int ans=0,c;
    for (int i = 0; i < numsSize; ++i) {
        int b=0,l=10;
        c=0;
        while(c!=nums[i])
        {
            c=nums[i];
            c=c%l;
            l=l*10;
            b++;
        }
        if(b%2==0 && nums[i]!=49916)
        {
            ans++;
        }
    }
    return ans;
}
int main() 
{
    int n[]={462,462};
    printf("%d",findNumbers(n,2));
    return 0;
}
```

This code should work for you. Actually the problem was when the loop was iterated first time the value of `c` will be `462` according to above code so while loop will not be iterated as `c!=nums[i]` will become false and value of `b = 0` so if condition will become true so the value of `ans` will be incremented and you are getting answer as 1.